# Hide 'Pay Now' button in WooCommerce Simple Auctions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide the 'Pay Now' button that displays after an auction is won with the WooCommerce Simple Auctions plugin. I have tried and tried but never managed doing it and now I'm stuck. I could simply hide the button using CSS, but the problem is that there are more functions using the same div class both various plugins and my theme. And if I change the div class in the plugin's source code, the next update might reset it to default. So I want to hide it with a function in my theme's functions.php instead.

Thank you so much for taking your time helping me with this.

`woocommerce_simple_auction_pay_now_button` is the hook/filter for the 'Pay Now' button and here is the source code:

```
/**
             * Ajax finish auction
             *
             * Function for finishing auction with ajax when countdown is down to zero
             *
             * @access public
             * @param  array
             * @return string
             *
             */
            function ajax_finish_auction() {

                if (isset($_POST["post_id"])) {

                        usleep(mt_rand(2000000,5000000));
                        $product_data = wc_get_product( wc_clean( $_POST["post_id"] ) );
                        if ($product_data->is_closed()) {

                            if (isset($_POST["ret"]) && $_POST["ret"] != '0') {

                                if ($product_data->is_reserved()) {
                                    if (!$product_data->is_reserve_met()) {
                                        _e("Reserve price has not been met", 'wc_simple_auctions');
                                        die();
                                    }
                                }
                                if ($product_data->get_auction_current_bider()) {
                                    echo "<div>";
                                    printf(__("Winning bid is %s by %s.", 'wc_simple_auctions'), wc_price($product_data->get_curent_bid()), get_userdata($product_data->get_auction_current_bider())->display_name);
                                    if (get_current_user_id() == $product_data->get_auction_current_bider()){
                                        echo '<a href="'.apply_filters( 'woocommerce_simple_auction_pay_now_button',esc_attr(add_query_arg("pay-auction",$product_data->get_id(), simple_auction_get_checkout_url()))).'" class="button">'.__( 'Pay Now', 'wc_simple_auctions' ).'</a>';
                                    }
                                    echo "</div>";

                                } else {
                                    echo "<div>";
                                    _e("There were no bids for this auction.", 'wc_simple_auctions');
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    die();
                                }

                            }

                        } else {

                            echo "<div>";

                            if (isset($_POST["future"]) && $_POST["future"] == 'true') {
                                    printf(__("Auction has started please refresh page.", 'wc_simple_auctions'));
                            } elseif (isset($_POST["future"]) && $_POST["future"] == 'false') {
                                    printf(__("Auction has finished please refresh page.", 'wc_simple_auctions'));
                            } else {
                                    printf(__("Please refresh page.", 'wc_simple_auctions'));
                            }

                            echo "</div>";
                        }
                }
                die();
            }
```

Comment: The filter `woocommerce_simple_auction_pay_now_button` is not usable as it just acting on the href attribute (the button link)… So there is no hooks available for that.

Comment: Okay thank you for the info.